# Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, url

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't found an answer that solves my situation.

I'm looking at the Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view), and I've set up the first URLs exactly as the tutorial has it, word for word, but when I go to http://http://localhost:8000/polls/, it gives me this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/ ^% [name='index']
^admin/
The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

I'm using Django 1.10.5 and Python 2.7.

Here is the code I have in relevant url and view files:

In mysite/polls/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

In mysite/polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^%', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

In mysite/mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

What's going on? Why am I getting 404s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your url conf regex is incorrect, you have to use `$` instead of `%`.

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

The `$` acts as a regex flag to define the end of the regular expression.

Comment: Ugh, can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: Then the original django documentation is broken where it is desrcibed in a wrong way: [Writing your first Django app, part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Django version 1.x to 2.x changed from url to path.  

I'm new to Django, landed here while diagnosing errors following this tut/demo.
https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/django-auth-part1/  

I should have followed the official django tut first :)  

Using the URLconf defined in django_survey.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:  



blah.  


dropping link below to help alternate universe version of me time warp.  

https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/

Comment: you don't need to use Regex links in Django 3.0. I am still getting this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the path function to define a wildcard url `path('', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: @v1k45 that was my problem as well. Your solution fixed it for Django 3.1

Answer (score 2):

`urlpatterns = [path('', views.index, name='index'), ]`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with the tutorial!

The issue is that if you look closely it references **two** url.py files, mysite/polls/url.py and mysite/url.py.

Putting the provided code in the correct url.py files should correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding STATIC_URL and STATIC_MEDIA when debug is ON, helped me:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```